# Do C# access modifiers affect build times?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, build, msbuild

**Background:**

I help with maintenance of a large legacy ERP system with >6M lines of C#, divided amongst 180 assemblies.  Build times in vs2015 are longer than 5 minutes, and we are interested in ways to make this faster.

We already take advantage of many *.sln files to partition the projects into groups that make sense for various product feature-sets or infrastructure concerns.  This often means we can get away with building just a handful of the projects for some modifications.  - But not always, as the core infrastructure assemblies also host business logic: -->  Consequently, working on certain features affects dll's that are "core" dependencies, forcing us to rebuild all 180 projects.

Apart from fostering excessive inter-dependencies between assemblies, more than a decade of organic code growth has also produced overly permissive code unit accessibility (the "public" keyword shows up everywhere.)

**Question**

Could build times be improved by minimizing the accessibility of all types and members?

Comment: You should focus on dependencies between the projects. 5 minutes to build such a big solution is not much. The problem starts when a change in any project requires a full rebuild - but that's a problem of tightly coupled assemblies.

Comment: _"Could I improve build times by minimizing the accessibility of all types and members?"_ -- could _you_ improve _your_ build times? How would anyone here know the answer to that? You just need to try it and see. I can imagine there _might_ be an effect, depending on the effect accessibility has on the compiler's memory footprint, but unless you're compiling on a fairly old/low-memory system, you may not notice even such an effect.